# int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'

Tags: django

hi folks am trying to  call the model from Organiser model in sponsor  model and EventDetails from organizer model is referred  to sponsor model while fatching the primary key of eventDetail i am not able to get

views.py

```
if request.method =='POST':
    eventDetail =EventDetails()
    if EventDetails.objects.filter(pk=id,event=request.POST['event_title']).exists():
        event_id =eventDetail.id


    sponsor_ship=SponsorShipDetails(event_id=event_id,event_title=event_title,platinum_sponsor=platinum_sponsor,f_platinum=f_platinum,ex_platinum=ex_platinum,gold_sponsor=gold_sponsor,
                f_gold=f_gold,ex_gold=ex_gold,silver_sponsor=silver_sponsor,f_silver=f_silver,ex_silver=ex_silver)
            sponsor_ship.save()
```

model.py fromORganiser

```
class EventDetails(models.Model):

    event = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    no_participant = models.IntegerField()
    event_level = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    eligibility = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    prerequisite = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    facility = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    event_detail_docs = models.FileField(upload_to='event_details_docs')


class SponsorShipDetails(models.Model):

    event_id =models.OneToOneField(EventDetails,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True)
    event_title = models.CharField(max_length=100,default=True)
    platinum_sponsor =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    f_platinum = models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    ex_platinum=models.IntegerField()
    gold_sponsor =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    f_gold =models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    ex_gold = models.IntegerField()
    silver_sponsor= models.CharField(max_length=100)
    f_silver=models.TextField(max_length=1500)
    ex_silver = models.IntegerField()


TypeError at /Organizer/sponsorShipDetails
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/Organizer/sponsorShipDetails
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'
Exception `enter code here`Location:    D:\Workspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 965
Python Executable:  D:\Workspace\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.1
```

Answer (score 0):

In class SponsorShipDetails, you have declared event_id = OneToOneField on EventDetails but "event_id" doesn`t exists in class EventDetails. What exits is "event" which is not taken as primary key in SponsorShipDetails.
Change the name, of either